# Accessing a method from a different class in Java

Tags: java, methods

I'm writing a program and I want to access a method from a different class.  I know you are supposed to create a new object for the method you want to use, but every time I do that, it states, "The constructor Card() is undefined".  I don't want to access the constructor though, I want to access a different method in that class.

Here is the very beginning of my method I want to bring my "other" method in to. I tried creating a new object but it gives me an error on that part that's in between the ***__***:

```
public void addCard(Card[][]card) {
    Card card1;
    card1 = *new Card();*
```

The other method is simply called `getCard(int r, Suit s)` (this is in a different class). There is also a constructor method in this class and that's what the error seems to be talking about..?

If you could help that would be Great, thanks!

Here's my Card class:

```
public class Card {
private static Card[][] card = new Card[4][13];
private int rank;
public enum Suit{hearts, diamonds, clubs, spades};
private Suit suit;

private Card(int r, Suit s){
    this.suit = s;
    this.rank = r;
}

public int getRank(){
    return rank;
}

public Suit getSuit(){
    return suit;
}

public static Card[][] getCard(int r, Suit s){
    if(card == null){
        return card;
    }
    else{
        card = new Card[4][13];
        return card;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your Card class?

Comment: Is your Card method constructor is Parameterized?

Comment: Is `Card` an enum by an chance?

Comment: this is  due to You have a overloaded constructor in your class and you didn't write default constructor

Comment: Downvote for poor research effort.  Please at least make an effort to google your question title before posting.

Comment: dont make your constructor `private`

Comment: I did look it up on google first, I just couldn't figure out what I did wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You should instantiate a new object like that:

```
Card card = new Card();
```

On the other hand, if you have in your design to use methods of classes without instantiating objects of that class, then you are looking for the `static` keyword. **static** defined methods and variables are defined to be a property of the class rather than the object. So, you can use `static` methods without initializing the object.

```
public Class A{
  public static void methodName(){
    //you can call that methods from anywhere using A.methodName();
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow that was the problem...it was static.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

The constructor is called automatically when you try to setup an instance of the class.

A default no-args constructor is automatically generated for you as long as you don't create another constructor. Once you do, you **will need to specify** the no-args constructor yourself, like below.

```
public Card(){}
```

Answer (score 1):

when the user defines a parameterized constructor, the default constructor is not provided by the compiler, hence the user has to define a default constructor if he wishes to create objects by not giving parameters to the constructor.

```
public Card()
{
    //do something
}
```

looks like you have private constructor, change your constructor to the following

```
public Card(int r, Suit s)
{
    this.suit = s;
    this.rank = r;
}
```

Note: if you want to create Card objects in the following way:

```
Card card1;
card1 = new Card();
```

you can either define public no argument constructor(i.e public Card(){}) or nothing(in case of nothing : compiler will provide no argument constructor)

if you want to create Card objects in this fashion:

```
Card card1, card2;
card1 = new Card();
card2 =  new card(1,new Suit());
```

you have to include both the constructor as I have shown above.

Comment: These are included by default. You don't need to add it to have it be an option.

Comment: when the user defines a parameterized constructor, the default constructor is not provided by the compiler.

Comment: @Legend What do you mean by "included by default"

Comment: The JVM adds them automatically, such as importing java.lang, adding Object as a super class if non is stated, etc.

Comment: @Legend JVM will ONLY add if there are no other Constructors defined. Try to test that yourself.

Comment: @Legend after the creation of parameterized constructor, JVM hides the implementation of deafault constructor. After than you need to define a zero argument constructor if you need to create a non parameterized object

Answer (score 0):

When you write a constructor with argument then JVM hides the default construtor (with no parameters).So now you need to define a constructor with no arguments.So now you need to define a constructor

```
public Card(){
}
```

**OR** create object with parameterized constructor new Card(params)